# Every HTTP request I send gives a 401 Unauthorized code

Tags: apex, trigger, callout, httprequest

I'm working on a trigger that will send an HTTP request on some records creation/updates.

I have developed the method the trigger should execute, however, every single HTTP request I send gets a 401 code. I can manually put the request in a browser and get a 200/201 code, it's just when it runs from salesforce that the request is 401.

I am sending an access token as a header, the token works, and the site I'm sending the request to is in the Remote Sites list on org>setup (I am using a trailhead playground)

What can I do to fix this? Is this a limitation of the trailhead playground or am I doing something wrong?

sample code

```
public static HTTPResponse getResource(){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        
        req.setEndpoint('https://someWebsite.com/api/v1/SeeResource?');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        String authToken = 'myToken==';
        req.setHeader('access_token', authToken);
        req.setHeader('format', 'json');
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorization in a header would be in the Authorization header. It appears that you meant to use query string parameters instead:

```
String authToken = 'myToken==';
PageReference ref = new PageReference('https://someWebsite.com/api/v1/SeeResource');
ref.getParameters.putAll(new Map<String, String> {
  'access_token' => authToken,
  'format' => 'json'
});
String endpoint = ref.getUrl();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();    
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
return res;
```

However, without having some documentation, it's hard to tell what's going on.

I can say that there's a defined list of allowed headers, and they are [these headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers). Neither `access_token` nor `format` are acceptable; you'd have to prefix them with `X-` to be valid.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually mixing HTTP headers with params...I did mean to use params.

I changed my code to reflect yours, however, I'm still getting unauthorized while in Postman I get a good request.

This is the documentation for the API I'm querying https://dev.targetprocess.com/reference#userstories-get

Comment: I noticed that I had an unescaped character in my token, that was causing the issue! Thank you, it works now!

Comment: @ThePorcius Grat. Glad I could help a bit, at least.